# Can you use the same token in ADFS for 2 different relying parties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, adfs

Currently I have 2 relying parties setup in the same ADFS server; one for my web api and one setup for MVC application.  When I get the token for authenticating in MVC app I capture this token to send it to my web api for authentication as well. This token does not work for the web api.
If I specifically make a new call for that relying party(web api) it will work so i think that it is setup correctly in ADFS...
Is there a configuration issue in ADFS not not allow the same token to work for both?

Is this even possible?

Is this the wrong architecture in ADFS?

Should I use one relying party for both apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Identity Delegation which helps in scenarios like this where an app calls a service instead of a user.

This similar question has some good resources:
[Pass ADFS Token to a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797698/pass-adfs-token-to-a-service)